# Is every incomplete metric space meagre in itself?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

From the Baire category theorem, we have that every complete metric space is non-meagre. I am curious what happens when the space is not complete.

Examples or counter-examples are highly appreciated.

Definition:

A subset of a topological space is meagre if it is a countable union of nowhere dense sets,

Comment: The condition that countable intersections of dense opens is dense is equivalent to every nonempty open subspace being nonmeager, and also equivalent to every comeager subspace being dense. So if you have a space which does not satisfy the Baire category theorem, you will get an open meager subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, being non-meagre (in itself) is a *topological* property, while being complete (as a metric space) is *not*. So you have a mismatch: $(0,1)$ is not complete (in its standard metric), but is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$, which is. As the latter is non-meagre, so is the former. So $(0,1)$ is a trivial example of a non-complete, non-meagre metric space.

More interesting is whether there is a non-completely metrisable space $X$ that is non-meagre. the property of "being completely metrisable" *is* a topological property. Baire implies that all completely metrisable spaces are non-meagre. But that fails too: $((\Bbb R \times (0,+\infty)) \cup (\Bbb Q \times \{0\})$ (subspace topology from $\Bbb R^2$) is a standard example of a non-meagre metric space that is not completely metrisable.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\bf Q$ is meager because it is a countable union of points (which are of empty interior). The set $(0,1)$ endowed with its standard topology is not complete. It is not meager either because it is homeomorphic to $\bf R$ and being meager in oneself is invariant by homeomorphism.

The Baire category theorem is not only true for complete metric space but also for all spaces homeomorphic to such spaces.